# How to connect to docker selenium/hub from python

Tags: python, selenium, docker, selenium-grid

I want to run multiple selenium browsers in same time and as described here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#docker-images-for-selenium-standalone-server-hub-and-node-configurations-with-chrome-and-firefox

the solution for this will be using `selenium/hub`. Before I use `selenium/standalone-firefox-debug` with following configuration:

```
services:
  django: &django
    links:
      - firefox
  firefox:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox-debug
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
      - 5900:5900
```

And was able to connect to browser from code like:

```
browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://firefox:4444/wd/hub',
                                  desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
```

or from `VNC` to `localhost:5900`

But after I setup selenium hub from this [example](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#version-2) I can't figure out how do I can connect to `remoteDriver` and to `VNC`. What address to use, where do I monitor running browsers, etc. ?